# Apex chart displaying blank (white) in vue js

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

[image]

I am using vue.js to display apex chart. but it's just displaying blank and taking up space.
I have given my code below. can you help me where did I go wrong, and how do I fix it?

```
<template>
  <div class="example">
    <VueApexCharts
      width="500"
      height="350"
      type="candlestick"
      :options="chartOptions"
      class="outline"
      :series="series"
    ></VueApexCharts>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive } from 'vue';
import VueApexCharts from 'vue3-apexcharts';

let chartOptions = reactive({
  title: {
    text: 'CandleStick Chart Title That Doesnt Update',
    align: 'left',
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  },
  yaxis: {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
});

const series = reactive([
  {
    data: [
      {
        x: new Date(1538778600000),
        y: [6629.81, 6650.5, 6623.04, 6633.33],
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538780400000),
        y: [6632.01, 6643.59, 6620, 6630.11],
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538782200000),
        y: [6630.71, 6648.95, 6623.34, 6635.65],
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538784000000),
        y: [6635.65, 6651, 6629.67, 6638.24],
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538785800000),
        y: [6638.24, 6640, 6620, 6624.47],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
</script>
```